# Improve algorithm for 'Get element in a list or dictionary in an elegant way using list or str as key'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have [this function](https://gist.github.com/av1m/3517b2eff6615c7c12a6cb31aa86fe5d)

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem
from typing import Any, Mapping, Union


def getdeep(data: Mapping, map_list: Union[list, str], default: Any = None) -> Any:
    """Iterate nested dictionary|list and can return default value if key not found

    This methods can handle list of keys as well as string of keys separated by dot.

    Example:
        >>> data = {'a': {'b': {'c': 1}}}
        >>> getdeep(data, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
        1
        >>> getdeep(data, 'a.b.c')
        1
        >>> getdeep(data, ['a', 'b', 'D'], default=0)
        0
        >>> getdeep(data, 'a.b.D', default=0)
        0
        >>> getdeep({data: ["a", "b", "c"]}, "data.1")
        'b'
        >>> getdeep({data: ["a", "b", "c"]}, ["data", 1])
        'b'
        >>> getdeep(["a": {"j": "e"} "b", "c"], ["data", "0.j"])
        'e'

    :param data: dictionary or list to iterate
    :type data: Mapping
    :param map_list: list of keys or string of keys separated by dot
    :type map_list: list or str
    :param default: default value to return if key not found
    :type default: Any
    :return: value of key or default value
    :rtype: Any
    """
    try:
        if isinstance(map_list, str):
            map_list = map_list.split(".")
            # Transform string integer keys to int
            map_list = [
                int(key) if isinstance(key, str) and key.isdigit() else key
                for key in map_list
            ]
        return reduce(getitem, map_list, data)
    except (KeyError, IndexError, TypeError):
        return default
```

I try to reduce the execution time of this function but i can't reach my goal...

The notation `data[..][..][..]` is very efficient in term of execution time; I have a big difference (I perform tests on very very large datasets)

An exemple :

```py
# Import data for example
import requests, time
data = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/commits').json()

# Compute with the getdeep function
start = time.time()
getdeep(data, "10.parents.0.sha")
method1 = time.time() - start

# Compute with the traditional method
start = time.time()
data[10]['parents'][0]['sha']
method2 = time.time() - start
```

Here, we can see that method2 is always lower (basically is normal, but there is a big difference).

I can also note that using a list instead of a string makes it possible not to enter the if of the getdeep function. This is reflected in the execution time

Comment: Provide an example of data (or, more likely, code to generate data) for which the function is unacceptably slow.

Comment: @Kodiologist i put a simple example. I didn't want to put too much, but in my tests I iterate over a whole big dictionary and I repeat each test 1000 times while taking an average. (i use https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit)

Comment: On my machine, method 1 takes about 20 μs whereas method 2 takes about 1.5 μs. I don't think you can approach the speed of native operators for a single fast query like this because of the inherent overhead in string processing, calling functions, and so on. If you were calling `getdeep` many times in a loop or on a much larger structure, there might be ways to amortize these costs. Ultimately, I think this isn't a good example, because 20 μs is fast.

Comment: I'm just wondering about the optimality of this function. The idea is to make the code cleaner. I know we can't have the same performance as using native operators. Only, is such a "slowness" acceptable for a function of this type (which is enormously solicited in a program).

Comment: If you don't have a specific problem you're trying to solve, you might be interested in a different Stack Exchange site, Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour